# How to get all strings instances following a custom pattern from a variable to an array in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

**The Problem**

Using Bash, I have a variable with a string like this one:

```
STR="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pharetra metus turpis, id rutrum massa auctor.
not ok 1 Chrome 89.0 - [158 ms] - Failed test 1 | Test Name 1
    ---
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pharetra metus turpis, id rutrum massa auctor.
not ok 2 Chrome 89.0 - [158 ms] - Failed test 2 | Test Name 2
    ---
ok 1 Chrome 89.0 - [158 ms] - Passing...
    ---"
```

And I need to create an array containing only the name of those failing tests.
The pattern/rules would be:

- Lines starting with the 'not ok' phrase.
- Then, Getting the text after the second dash until the end end-of-line.

**What I have tried**

So far, I came up the following regexs:

1. `(not ok )(.*?)(\n)`, that will match the first rule.
2. `(?:[^-]*\-){2}([^-]*)`, that will match the second rule.

**What I am missing**

However, I am very lost on how to combine them together to generate the final desire output (an array in bash):

```
[
'Failed test 1 | Test Name 1',
'Failed test 2 | Test Name 2'
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F ' - ' '/not ok /{print $3}' <<< "$str"

Failed test 1 | Test Name 1
Failed test 2 | Test Name 2
```

To create a bash array use:

```sh
readarray -t arr < <(awk -F ' - ' '/not ok /{print $3}' <<< "$s")

# check array content
declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="Failed test 1 | Test Name 1" [1]="Failed test 2 | Test Name 2")
```

Comment: Thanks for this @anubhava, it is almost perfect for what I need. 
Then only thing missing would be not to get what is after the last dash, but after the second dash (exactly. 
This since the test name might have some dashes there...

Comment: In that case use `print $3` instead of `print $NF`

Comment: The master of awk and bash :-) ++

Comment: Thanks again @anubhava, I used your solution with a small change: 
IFS=$'\n'
arr=($(awk -F ' - ' '/not ok /{print $3}' <<< "$@"

since readarray seems not to be working on my mac.

Comment: Yes `readarray` requires bash ver 4+ and I have it installed using `home brew` on my mac

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` and `sed`, this one-liner may be what you're looking for:

```
readarray -t failed_tests < <(sed -n '/^not ok/s/[^-]*-[^-]*- //p' <<< "$STR")
```

The failed tests will be read into the array `failed_tests`. You can print them by

```
printf '%s\n' "${failed_tests[@]}"
```

Alternatively, in plain `bash` without using any external utility:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r; do
    [[ $REPLY = 'not ok'* ]] && failed_tests+=("${REPLY#*-*- }")
done <<< "$STR"

printf '%s\n' "${failed_tests[@]}"
```

Yet another alternative could be to use a `grep` with Perl regex support:

```
readarray -t failed_tests < <(grep -Po '^not ok[^-]*-[^-]*- \K.*' <<< "$STR")
```

---

If `bash` version doesn't support `readarray`, `readarray -t failed_tests` can be replaced by `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a failed_tests`